# Vue.js 2: Scoped style not working with sass/scss

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In my Vue.js component when I set the style to "scoped", the styles are ignored:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
```

I get the following error in the console:

```
[HMR] unexpected require(609) to disposed module
```

It's working as expected if I don't add the "scoped" attribute.

Comment: What happens when you stop your dev server and then start it again ?

Comment: Upon further investigation it works for elements already existing in the dom but it doesn't work for elements added dynamically with d3 for example.

Comment: Of course it won't work for things created outside of Vue - if you want to style such things you need specially crafted selectors.

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV, I thought that anything that was created within a component could be scoped. Do you want to write your comment as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer.

When you work with scoped style(s) Vue adds `data` attribute with an unique value to all tags in your component and then silently modifies your CSS/SASS selectors to rely on this `data` attribute.

For example, `.list-container:hover` becomes `.list-container[data-v-21e5b78]:hover`

If you need a deep selector - that is, which affects child components - you can use a combinator

```
<style scoped>
.a >>> .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```

which will be compiled into

```
.a[data-v-f3f3eg9] .b { /* ... */ }
```

If SASS is unable to parse the `>>>` combinator you can replace it with `/deep/` instead.

If you do not use the combinator then

```
<style scoped>
.a > .b { /* ... */ }
</style>
```

would be compiled into

```
.a > .b[data-v-f3f3eg9] { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: Thanks @IVOGELOV. By any chance would you know if there is a way to get the data-v attribute that will be generated (ex: "data-v-f3f3eg9") so that it could be added to elements created dynamically?

Comment: You will have to look in the source code of `vue-loader` to see how this attribute is generated. I would not do it myself - instead, try to build your selectors using the >>> combinator. It is not a replacement for > - it simply states that the class on the left will target the `data-v` attribute.

Comment: The >>> combinator works fine, it's just that there are cases when I need to use it in conjunction with extending styles (@extend) I don't get the expected result. I just used specially crafted selectors instead.

Comment: Thanks. 
/deep/ is very important for compiled SCSS / SASS.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `::v-deep` combinator to target scoped styles of a child component.

Example:

```html
<template>
  <main class="content">
    <child-component></child-component>
  </main>
</template>
```

In this case, if you wanted to change the color of paragraphs `<p>` in the child component, you could do what with:

```css
.content ::v-deep p {
  color: red;
}
```