# styling active links in Vue using Bulma

Tags: css, vue.js, bulma

The following buttons are being used for navigation on a page in a VueJS app:

```
<div class="box button title" @click="updateMenu()" :class="componentName == 'central' ? 'is-primary' : ''"><router-link to="/home/central">Central</router-link></div>
<div class="box button title" @click="updateMenu()" :class="componentName == 'validation' ? 'is-primary' : ''"><router-link to="/home/validation">Validation</router-link></div>
<div class="box button title" @click="updateMenu()" :class="componentName == 'list' ? 'is-primary' : ''"><router-link to="/home/production">List</router-link></div>
```

Here is a snippet of the setup for the router:

```
export default new VueRouter({
  routes,
  linkActiveClass: "active",      // active class for non-exact links
  linkExactActiveClass: "active"  // active class for exact links
});
```

Bulma is the CSS framework being used in this project and the variables related to link styles are set up as follows in a file called index.scss:

```
$link: $primary;
$link-invert: $primary-invert;
$link-focus-border: $primary;
$link-active: $white;
```

Here is the current behavior using this code:

- when a button is clicked the background color of the button changes to the color setup for "is-primary" (this is good)
- text in the button remains "is-primary" color (this is bad) - it was expected to change to white

Why isn't `$link-active: $white;` changing the clicked link's text to white?

As a test, when this is added to the same page as the nav buttons then the link text of the active button does change to white:

```
<style scoped>
.active {
    color: white;
}
</style>
```

The above test is not OK for Production code - the fix for this should be in a Bulma variable settings somewhere.  But where/how, is the question.

Comment: removing `scoped` doesn't solve the problem?

Comment: The goal is to fix this issue using variables in the .scss class and not use `<style>` tags at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely SASS/SCSS scoping stuff.

Reference to IVO: [Vue.js 2: Scoped style not working with sass/scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470954/vue-js-2-scoped-style-not-working-with-sass-scss)

is either u go `/deep/` or `::v-deep`  in your styling.