# Vue JS Media Query does not work, it does not overwrite the base css even if it is in the correct hierarchy

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

For some reason SCSS does not work as it is supposed to work, I have all my styles in a correct hierarchy, I have base CSS on top, and them media queries underneath, but for some reason I need to write - !important at the end of all the properties I overwrite, otherwise it does not work.

Styles:

```
    /* ***********Registration************** */

.register {
  text-align: center;
  .register_choices-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    .register_choices {
      width: 50%;
      display: flex;
      p,
      input,
      form {
        display: inline;
      }
      form {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
        width: 80%;
      }
      input:hover {
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      label {
        margin-left: 6px;
      }
    }
  }
  .register_inputs {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    input {
      width: 50%;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
    .formButton {
      width: 50%;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
  }
}

/* ******************************** */
```

Media Queries:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .register_choices {
    width: 50%;
    display: block;
    p {
      text-align: left;
    }
    form {
      flex-wrap: wrap;

      width: 100%;
      div:nth-child(1) {
        margin-left: 0;
      }
    }
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .register_choices form {
    display: block;
  }
  form input {
    width: 70%;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 510px) {
  form input {
    width: 90%;
  }
}
```

And index.scss so you could see hierarchy is correct

```
@import "colors";
@import "fonts";
@import "fontSizes";
@import "classes";
@import "animations";
@import "styles";
@import "mediaq";
```

Media queries ar imported last.

Answer (score 1):

> SCSS does not work as it is supposed to work

Try "deep" `>` in your `<style scoped>` or `::v-deep` combinator?

Vue adds `data` attr with an unique value to all tags in your component and then silently modifies your CSS/SASS selectors to rely on this data attribute.

[Vue.js 2: Scoped style not working with sass/scss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51470954/vue-js-2-scoped-style-not-working-with-sass-scss)